# Housing steps and requirements in Caesar 3

Tags: caesar-3

In Caesar 3, you need to provide new services for a house to evolve, from small tents all the way up to luxury palace.

What are each steps with the corresponding required service?

Answer (score 14):

Source: [Appian Way (Wayback machine copy of defunct website)](https://web.archive.org/web/20060713205809/http://caesaralan.co.uk/strategy/houselevels.html)

## Housing levels with required services:

| Housing Level | Desirab. | Entert. | Services | Goods |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Small Tent | -99 | 0 | None! |  |
| Large Tent | -10 | 0 | Water |  |
| Small Shack | -5 | 0 |  | 1 Food Type |
| Large Shack | 0 | 0 | Temple to 1 God |  |
| Small Hovel | 4 | 0 | Clean Water 4 |  |
| Large Hovel | 8 | 10 |  |  |
| Small Casa | 12 | 10 | School or Library |  |
| Large Casa | 16 | 10 | Baths | Pottery |
| Small Insulae | 20 | 25 |  |  |
| Medium Insulae | 25 | 25 | Doctor or Hospital | Furniture |
| Large Insulae | 32 | 25 | School & Library Barber | Oil |
| Grand Insulae | 40 | 35 |  | 2nd Food Type |
| Small Villa | 48 | 35 | Temples to 2 Gods | Wine |
| Medium Villa | 53 | 40 | Doctor & Hospital |  |
| Large Villa | 58 | 45 | Academy |  |
| Grand Villa | 63 | 50 | Temples to 3 Gods | 3rd Food Type |
| Small Palace | 68 | 55 |  | 2 Types of Wine |
| Medium Palace | 74 | 60 |  |  |
| Large Palace | 80 | 70 | Hippodrome |  |
| Luxury Palace | 90 | 80 | All of them! | Everything! |

---

## Housing levels with population, prosperity factor, and tax multiplier.

(for details, refer to the original website)

| Housing Level | Size | Population | Prosp Factor | Tax Mult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Small Tent | 1x1 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| Large tent | 1x1 | 7 | 10 | 1 |
| Small Shack | 1x1 | 9 | 15 | 1 |
| Large Shack | 1x1 | 11 | 20 | 1 |
| Small Hovel | 1x1 | 13 | 25 | 2 |
| Large Hovel | 1x1 | 15 | 30 | 2 |
| Small Casa | 1x1 | 17 | 35 | 2 |
| Large Casa | 1x1 | 19 | 45 | 2 |
| Small Insulae | 1x1 | 19 | 50 | 3 |
| Medium Insulae | 1x1 | 20 | 58 | 3 |
| Large Insulae | 2x2 | 84 | 65 | 3 |
| Grand Insulae | 2x2 | 84 | 80 | 4 |
| Small Villa | 2x2 | 40 | 150 | 9 |
| Medium Villa | 2x2 | 42 | 180 | 10 |
| Large Villa | 3x3 | 90 | 400 | 11 |
| Grand Villa | 3x3 | 100 | 600 | 11 |
| Small Palace | 3x3 | 106 | 700 | 12 |
| Medium Palace | 3x3 | 112 | 900 | 12 |
| Large Palace | 4x4 | 190 | 1500 | 15 |
| Luxury Palace | 4x4 | 200 | 1750 | 16 |

Comment: I think you forgot theater and amphitheater.

Answer (score -1):

A more detailed info in a single table can be found [here](http://mmxl.wz.cz/c3a/housing.html). For posterity it's copied below (the last four columns are about Desirability):

#### Housing Levels

| Level | Housing | Size | Pop. | Requirements | Prosp. Rating | Entert. Required | Tax Mult. | Crime | Effect | Range | Devolve | Evolve |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vacant Lot | 1x1 | 0 | Road access | 0 | - | - | - | 0 | 0 | - | - |

##### Plebeians: working citizens

| Level | Housing | Size | Pop. | Requirements | Prosp. Rating | Entert. Required | Tax Mult. | Crime | Effect | Range | Devolve | Evolve |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Small Tent | 1x1 2x2 | 5/20 | Immigrants | 5 | 0 | 1 | 25+3 | -3 | 3 | -99 | -10 |
| 2 | Large Tent | 1x1 2x2 | 7/28 | Well or Fountain | 10 | 0 | 1 | 25+3 | -3 | 3 | -12 | -5 |
| 3 | Small Shack | 1x1 2x2 | 9/36 | 1 type of food | 15 | 0 | 1 | 25+3 | -2 | 2 | -7 | 0 |
| 4 | Large Shack | 1x1 2x2 | 11/44 | 1 god | 20 | 0 | 1 | 25+3 | -2 | 2 | -2 | 4 |
| 5 | Small Hovel | 1x1 2x2 | 13/52 | Fountain | 25 | 0 | 2 | 22+3 | -2 | 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 6 | Large Hovel | 1x1 2x2 | 15/60 | 1 entertainment | 30 | 10 | 2 | 22+3 | -2 | 2 | 6 | 12 |
| 7 | Small Casa | 1x1 2x2 | 17/68 | School or Library | 35 | 10 | 2 | 17+2 | -1 | 1 | 10 | 16 |
| 8 | Large Casa | 1x1 2x2 | 19/76 | Baths, pottery | 45 | 10 | 2 | 17+2 | -1 | 1 | 14 | 20 |
| 9 | Small Insulae | 1x1 2x2 | 19/76 | 2 entertainments | 50 | 25 | 3 | 17+2 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 25 |
| 10 | Medium Insulae | 1x1 2x2 | 20/80 | Doctor or Hospital, furniture | 58 | 25 | 3 | 17+2 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 32 |
| 11 | Large Insulae | 2x2 | 84 | School and Library, Barber, oil | 65 | 25 | 3 | 12+2 | 0 | 0 | 29 | 40 |
| 12 | Grand Insulae | 2x2 | 84 | 2 types of food, 3 entertainments | 80 | 35 | 4 | 12+2 | 0 | 0 | 37 | 48 |

##### Patricians: paying citizens

| Level | Housing | Size | Pop. | Requirements | Prosp. Rating | Entert. Required | Tax Mult. | Crime | Effect | Range | Devolve | Evolve |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Small Villa | 2x2 | 40 | 2 gods, wine | 150 | 35 | 9 | 8+1 | +1 | 2 | 45 | 53 |
| 14 | Medium Villa | 2x2 | 42 | Doctor and Hospital | 180 | 40 | 10 | 8+1 | +1 | 2 | 50 | 58 |
| 15 | Large Villa | 3x3 | 90 | Academy | 400 | 45 | 11 | 8+1 | +2 | 2 | 55 | 63 |
| 16 | Grand Villa | 3x3 | 100 | 3 types of food, 3 gods | 600 | 50 | 11 | 8+1 | +2 | 2 | 60 | 68 |
| 17 | Small Palace | 3x3 | 106 | 2 types of wine | 700 | 55 | 12 | 5+1 | +3 | 6 | 65 | 74 |
| 18 | Medium Palace | 3x3 | 112 | 4 gods | 900 | 60 | 12 | 5+1 | +3 | 6 | 70 | 80 |
| 19 | Large Palace | 4x4 | 190 | Hippodrome | 1500 | 70 | 15 | 5+1 | +4 | 6 | 76 | 90 |
| 20 | Luxury Palace | 4x4 | 200 | everything | 1750 | 80 | 16 | 5+1 | +4 | 6 | 85 | 100 |